# Execution group not starting Websphere message broker 8

Tags: runtime-error, ibm-integration-bus

We have Websphere Message Broker v8.0.0.3 on Redhat Linux env, and we encounterd the following runtime error message:

```
BIP2057 
Execution Group <insert_1> could not be started: broker name <insert_2>; UUID <insert_3>; label <insert_4>; Pub-Sub server <insert_5> (1=Yes, 0=No).
```

The situation is that one of the execution groups stopped (without any trace/log about it) and the wmb could not auto start with the BIP2057 error.

the weird part occurs when another EG restarted (unlinked reason to the first problem, because of some applicative errors) and then the first EG "took its place", started successfully, and now the second EG could not start for the same reason.

We have checked for user permissions or the logs without any success in identifying the problem.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

- Run the following service IBM MQSeries if it's not running already:

  ***C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere MQ\bin\amqlsvc.exe***

If it gives an
   exception of **Access Denied**, your user must not be having rights to
   log on.

- Another possible resolution can be by restarting the
  DataFlowEngine.exe process.
- If none of the above scenarios fulfill the need, restart the system.

Comment: hi, we are running on linux, not windows.. also the user has all of the privilages it needs